# Get content string (not source code) of webPage on Android

Tags: javascript, android, json

I made a Javascript page to generate a JSON object for read it then from Android device.
I read it with the following code

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();

        if (statusCode == 200){
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                stringBuilder.append(line);
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("JSON", "Failed to donwload file");
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The problem is that this code returns the source code of the webpage, and the source code is the script in Javascript, not the JSON string generated after execute it. 
I need the JSON string and I need use Javascript to generate the JSON string because I access to an external service.

I haven't find any solution for this. I don't care if the possible solution involves the server or the Android terminal.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
String myresponse=Html.escapeHtml(YourStringHere);
```

Comment: If I escape the html tags I'll have nothing, because the JSON object is generated by the javascript (on the client side). I mean I only get the javascript source. The problem is that I don't get the JSON string.

Comment: make sure the Url you used doesn't redirecting to another url.other wise it will return you Source code not JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
private class MyJavaScriptInterface {

     private MyJavaScriptInterface () {
      }

    public void setHtml(String contentHtml) {

                    //here you get the content html
    }
}
private WebViewClient webViewClient = new WebViewClient() {


 @Override
 public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
     view.loadUrl("javascript:window.ResponseChecker.setHtml"
                    + "(document.body.innerHTML);");
        }
 }
```